# Newsoft json deserialize key as a value

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

How would i got about deserializing key from a json string as a value of an object?

Example:

```
{"vals": {"foo":{"val":1}, "bar":{"val":1}}}
```

Into

```
public Bizz
{
   public IList<Buzz> vals;
}
public Buzz
{
  public string name;
  public int val;
}
```

Where name would hold `foo/bar`.

Comment: You'd likely need to implement a [CustomJsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm).

Comment: A `[JsonKeyAttribute]` with a custom `JsonConverter`. I've had to write many custom JsonConverters because of bad JSON responses from 3rd parties, even within my own organization.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your custom Json Converter or you can simplify your Json a bit and go with `Dictionary<>` instead of `Buzz`. Is the Json generated by you?

To be able to convert to `Dictionary<>`, the Json should look like

```
{"foo":"1", "bar":"1"}
```

Comment: Sadly the json is not generated by my otherwise I would have just changed that.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous poster said, it naturally serialize it to a dictionary, say `serialized`, and then you can do:

```
var bizzes = new Bizz 
{
    vals = serialized
        .Select(kvp => new Buzz { name = kvp.Key, val = kvp.Value.val})
        .ToList()
}
```